# MongoDB refused to connect

Tags: mongodb

I seem to get this error when I launched `mongo`

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I did do the following:

- Delete the mongod.lock file
- Restart computer

Comment: I didnt read you restarted pc. Then probably some trouble with the storage. if you just learning remove the place where is stores files. May be somewhere under root

Comment: before I installed mongodb and it doesn't seem to work the first time (I tried restarting and starting the services, that didn't work)

Comment: Did you check which port the service is starting `mongod`? Another option: Why not start `mongod` manually?